Residue of $f(z)=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z-z^2}$ at $z=0$
I am trying to calculate the residue of $ f(z)=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z-z^2}$ at $z=0$ by noticing that
$$\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z}\frac{1}{1-z}=\left(\frac{1+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{(\frac{1}{z})^2}{2!}+ \dots}{z}\right)\left(1+z+z^2 + \dots\right)$$
so that then
$$\operatorname{Res}(0,f)=\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+ \dots=e.$$
I attempted verifying the result with WolframAlpha, but it didn't give me any output.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=residue+%28e%5E%281%2Fz%29%29%2F%28z-z%5E2%29
Wolfram is happy to find the residue at $z=1$, but it often struggles to find residues at non-pole singularities.

Yes, WolframAlpha struggles with such cases even if the input https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Residue%5Be%5E%281%2Fz%29%2F%28z-z%5E2%29%2C+%7Bz%2C+0%7D%5D is in Wolfram language.

Using the Residue theorem we have that, for $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$,
$$\mathop{\operatorname{Res}}_{z=0}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z-z^2}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\lvert z\rvert=\varepsilon}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z-z^2}\mathrm{d}z=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\lvert\zeta\rvert=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}\frac{e^\zeta}{\zeta-1}\mathrm{d}\zeta=\mathop{\operatorname{Res}}_{\zeta=1}\frac{e^\zeta}{\zeta-1}=\lim_{\zeta\to1}(\zeta-1)\frac{e^\zeta}{\zeta-1}=e,$$
where we have substituted $z=\frac{1}{\zeta}$, $\mathrm{d}z=-\frac{\mathrm{d}\zeta}{\zeta^2}$ and then gotten rid of the factor of $-1$ by reversing the orientation (to deal with the fact that the substitution itself also reverses orientation), and then finally observed that $\zeta\mapsto\frac{e^\zeta}{\zeta-1}$ has a simple pole at $\zeta=1$.

I also found the residue at $z=0$ to be $e$. In fact for this function, it seems easy enough to get the full Laurent expansion in the annulus $0<|z|<1$. Let’s write $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_nz^n$. Then of course, we have that for any $n\in\Bbb{Z}$ and any $1<R<\infty$,
\begin{align}
a_n&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=\frac{1}{R}}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\,dz\\
&=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=R}\zeta^{n+1}\cdot \frac{e^{\zeta}}{\frac{1}{\zeta}-\frac{1}{\zeta^2}}\cdot\left(-\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=R}\frac{\zeta^{n+1}e^{\zeta}}{\zeta-1}\,d\zeta\\
&=\text{Res}_{\zeta=0}\left(\frac{\zeta^{n+1}e^{\zeta}}{\zeta-1}\right) + \text{Res}_{\zeta=1}\left(\frac{\zeta^{n+1}e^{\zeta}}{\zeta-1}\right)\\
&= \text{Res}_{\zeta=0}\left(\frac{\zeta^{n+1}e^{\zeta}}{\zeta-1}\right)+ e.
\end{align}
Note that in the second equal sign, I made the change of variables $z=\frac{1}{\zeta}$ (the minus sign out front is because inversion is an orientation-reversing map), in the penultimate line I used the residue theorem, noting that the only possible poles are at $\zeta=0,1$, and in the final step, the residue evaluation at $\zeta=1$ is easy because the numerator is holomorphic about $\zeta=1$, so the residue is simply the numerator evaluated at $\zeta=1$. To evaluate the residue at $\zeta=0$, we split into two cases:

If $n\geq -1$, then the function is holomorphic about $\zeta=0$, and so the resiude is $0$, so $a_n=e$.
If $n\leq -2$, then for notation sake let’s define $m:=|n|-2=-n-2$, so that $n+1=-(m+1)$. Then,
\begin{align}
\text{Res}_{\zeta=0}\left(\frac{\zeta^{n+1}e^{\zeta}}{\zeta-1}\right)&=
\text{Res}_{\zeta=0}\left(\frac{e^{\zeta}}{\zeta^{m+1}(\zeta-1)}\right)= \text{coefficient of $\zeta^m$ in Taylor expansion of $\frac{e^{\zeta}}{\zeta-1}$}.
\end{align}
We can easily compute these Taylor coefficients:
\begin{align}
\frac{e^{\zeta}}{\zeta-1}=-\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta^k}{k!}\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\zeta^l\right)=-\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{\zeta^m}{k!}.
\end{align}
So, the coefficient of $\zeta^m$ is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^m\frac{1}{k!}$.

Hence, putting it all together (and keeping in mind that in the second case, $m=|n|-2$), we have
\begin{align}
a_n&=
\begin{cases}
e&\text{if $n\geq-1$}\\\\
e+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{|n|-2}\frac{1}{k!}&\text{if $n\leq -2$}.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
So, in particular, the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=0$ is $a_{-1}=e$.
